# Blade templating (Laravel) overwrite issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a "master" layout that has a section: `@yield('other-scripts')`

I use this master template in another view (`especie.blade.php`):

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@include('layouts.editarEspecie')

@section('other-scripts')
    {{ HTML::script('js/lightbox.js') }}
@stop
```

Inside `layouts.editarEspecie`, `@section('other-scripts')` is also overwritten:

```
@section('other-scripts')
    {{ HTML::script('js/chosen.jquery.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/chosenScriptModal.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/scripts.js') }}
@stop
```

The problem is that `@include('layouts.editarEspecie')` goes first, so `@section('other-scripts')` never adds the part inside `especie.blade.php`.

What can I do so that both part are added and it ends like this?

```
{{ HTML::script('js/chosen.jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/chosenScriptModal.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/scripts.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/lightbox.js') }}
```

P.S.: I do this because `lightbox.js` is always necessary, but `chosen.jquery.js, chosenScriptModal.js, scripts.js` may not always be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `layouts.editarEspecie` dont have a "section" - just have this:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/chosen.jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/chosenScriptModal.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/scripts.js') }}
```

Then those 3 lines will always be included.

Comment: The thing is, I don´t want those 3 lines to always go inside  `layouts.editarEspecie`, just when certain conditions are met (not shown here)

Comment: In that case try and use `@parent` (see here for more: http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) - otherwise call one of your sections a different name - you cant call them both `other-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is, I don´t want those 3 lines to always go inside 
>   layouts.editarEspecie, just when certain conditions are met (not shown
>   here)

ummmmm.. i know its like the fastest thing ever but you can always PHP if it

```
<?php
if (condition)
 {
 ?>
{{ script here}}
<?php
}
else
{}
?>
```

Sorry for lazy explanation but i am sure you get the hint